# Behavior of a gas as a function of frequency by transforming the Navier-Stokes equations into frequency using the Laplace transform?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, navier-stokes

How does a gas behave as a function of frequency and not of time by transforming the Navier-Stokes equations in the frequency domain using the Laplace transform?

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Laplace%20transform,(complex%20frequency)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Laplace%20transform,(complex%20frequency)).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations

Comment: The Naiver Stokes equations are non-linear in the dependent variables.  How do you transform non-linear equations using LT?

Comment: There is no prohibition to use it on nonlinear systems. We can even use the transform of the place Z in the discrete domain.

Answer (score 1):

The gas behavior doesn't change; the way the process is described is what changes. In equations such as Navier-Stokes, the process is described in terms of how it changes versus time. This is called a function in the "time domain" - time is the domain (input) of the function. This is typically an intuitive way for humans to think about a process - now it's like this, next it's like that, etc. However it is not the only way.

Let's first talk about a simpler cousin of the Laplace transform: the Fourier transform. When a function is passed through the Fourier transform, the output is a description of how the process "changes" versus frequency. It is now a function in the "frequency domain", as frequency is the domain (input) of the function.

But "change" is a poor word choice because for us it is always strongly associated with time. Maybe a better way is that it describes the characteristics of the process in terms of frequency.

A time domain function tells us what the characteristics of a process are at any given "point" in time. It may have a positive value, a negative value, or be zero, etc (it may of course also have a complex value).

A frequency domain function tells us what the characteristics of a process are at any given "point" in frequency. It may have a value (this frequency exists in the process) or be zero (it does not), etc.

The Laplace transform extends the Fourier transform so that the new domain is "s", which is a complex number $\sigma+j\omega$, referred to as *complex frequency*.

For functions which are valid in the context of the Laplace (or Fourier) transform, each representation (time domain or frequency domain) is a *complete and equivalent* representation.